# How to pass php object or array to Vue prop (Not Blade)?

Tags: php, vue.js, codeigniter

This Not Blade, it's just a regular php file containing the inline-template of my vue component, so I have no access to the typical laravel/blade {!! !!} shorthand.

This is an old Codeigniter project I'm migrating to Vue for the frontend and their way to bring data to their plain js script contained on php files was like:

```
var a = <?= json_encode($frontLanguage) ?>;
console.log(a);
```

which ouputted:
[image]

I tried something similar with Vue like

```
<vue-component a-string="<?='something string'?>" :language='<?=json_encode($frontLanguage)?>' inline-template>
```

a-string just works as it's just a string, but :language breaks the entire component, tried without json_encode, tried using double and single quotes, with and without colon, etc with no avail.

In the object I see html characters so that may be the reason? I'm not entirely sure
What would be the proper way of bringing this object for Vue to use as a prop?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is, if you use double quotes `"` to wrap the object, you need to use single quotes `'` in your json object. The best way to solve your issue is to use html encoded json string like `:language="<?=html encoded json string ?>"`. The reason for the problem of your data is, that there is a single quote inside one of the strings `'Personally...`. If you are using Vue 2, you need to test, which html entities are decoded by the vue compiler.

Comment: An example would be `:your-props="{&quot;prop&quot;: &quot;some text with &#39;Single&#39; quotes and also \&quot;double\&quot; quotes in it&quot; }"`

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you a full answer here: The reason, why there is a problem is, that either you need to use `"` or `'` for your html attribute. This leads to the problem, that you might have both of them inside your json output.

To avoid that, you need to encode html entities inside your json string like

```php-template
<vue-component :language="<?php htmlentities(json_encode($frontLanguage), ENT_QUOTES) ?>" />
```